# Manually validate antd form field against another field

Tags: reactjs, validation, antd

I'm trying to validate two fields(lower value, upper value) which is link to another. Lower and Upper values are required and always lower value should smaller than upper value. This is what i want to validate on real time when user type the inputs.

This is what i did so far(link below). I'm using `setFields` to manually set errors to fields. but the issue is when I'm typing the upper value the validation error message not showing. Is there any better way of doing this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hermann-l2pgw?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You can define your validation rule for lowerEnd as follows:

```js
const rules = {
  lowerEnd: [
    { required: true, message: 'Required' },
    (formInstance) => ({
      message: 'Lower must not be greater than upper',
      validator(rule, value) {
        if (value === null) {
          return Promise.resolve();
        }
        const upperValue = formInstance.getFieldValue('lowerEnd');
        if (value > upperValue) {
          return Promise.reject(new Error());
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
      },
    }),
  ],
  upperEnd: [{ required: true, message: 'Required' }],
};
```

And in your form component have it like this:

```js
   return (
    <Form form={form} name="new-form" autoComplete="off">
      <Form.Item
        label="Lower end"
        name="lowerEnd"
        rules={rules.lowerEnd}
      >
        <InputNumber />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Upper end"
        name="upperEnd"
        rules={rules.upperEnd}
      >
        <InputNumber />
      </Form.Item>

      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Form>
```

And a final note for those who are like me were struggling to make such a validation in form list: `rule` object in `validator` fn contains a field name so field index can be extracted from it.